# prevent user to click button until service response angular 7 rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am looking for efficient solution to avoid user to click the submit button again and again until they get response from backend API.

I have thought following solution but looking for any other ways to handle this.

1. use loader which will disable whole html until we get some response.
2. use exhaustmap to avoid multiple http calls
3. use throttletime which will manually not allow user to click for specific time period.

Please guide me if there is any other solutions which we can use.

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend to use `exhaustMap()` as primary solution in this case.
In template:

```
<button (click)="submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

then in your component:

```
submit$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

constructor() {
  this.submit$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(() => this.http.get("api/endpoint"))
  ).subscribe(res => {});
}

submitForm() {
  this.submit$.next(true);
}
```

You click 'Submit' and all proceeding click events will be ignored by `exhaustMap()` operator until HttpClient instance returns response and get completed.

Comment: Works very well!!

Comment: This is the best response I've found for my case, I just wanted to block subsequent the requests to be blocked until the one requested completes. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable the button itself till you get a response by having a flag in your component's controller file.

// in component's controller

```
loading = false;
.
...
submit(): void {
  loading = true;
  this.someserive.getData().pipe(finalize(() => this.loading = false).subcribe(...
  .
  ....
}
```

// in component's template

```
<button [disabled]="loading" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
```